# Connecting to a remote ArangoDB dockerized server

Tags: docker, deployment, arangodb

I am a beginner in regards to ArangoDB and I am trying to deploy my first project using it. The website is PHP based - what I did is that I created an Arango Docker container on Digital Ocean so that I can access it from the browser with the ipv4 provided. Public access to port 8529 is enabled. Locally, I am able to modify the .config file in order to point to the corresponding ip and I can painlessly retrieve data.

As a hosting provider I am using one.com. When uploading the same files that I am able to run locally on my own domain I get the following error:

`["_database":"ArangoDBClient\Connection":private]=> string(7) "_system" } ArangoDBClient\ConnectException: cannot connect to endpoint 'tcp://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8529/': Connection timed out`

I want to mention that I have also tried out ArangoOasis. No luck with it - I get the same error. Been at it for quite a few weeks - I would very much use some guidance. Even what to do next as I am out of ideas and documentation to read.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! Are you able to run your PHP project on your VM and see if it is working?

Comment: I'm pretty sure one.com does not allow outgoing traffic to arbitrary ports - as far as I can tell, you are expected to use the db solutions provided - I may be wrong though, did you contact the one.com support to clarify this?